# SQL How to find the totals grouped by a feild, on a particular Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem getting total accounts by location as of a particular date using SQL.

I have 5 tables, `locations`, `users`,`users_locations`, `deposits`, and `transactions` tables.
A user belongs to a location and has an account balance that is deducted when a transaction is done and increases when a deposit is made.

I need to produce a query that returns total accounts balance by Summing the account_bal field in the user's Table grouped by location on a part particular Date

```
USERS

| user_id |   name    |   account_bal  |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
|    1    |   Wells   |      -5        |
|    2    |   James   |     100        |
|    3    |   Joy     |       0        |
|    4    |   Mwaka   |       0        |

USERS_LOCATIONS

| user_id |  loc_id   |
|---------|-----------|
|    1    |   2       |
|    2    |   1       | 
|    3    |   3       |
|    4    |   4       |

DEPOSITS
| id      |   user_id |   amount  |   date      |
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------------
|    1    |       1   |      5    |  2021-04-26 |
|    2    |       3   |      10   |  2021-04-26 |
|    3    |       3   |      5    |  2021-04-25 |
|    4    |       4   |      5    |  2021-04-25 |

TRANSACTIONS

| id      |   user_id |   amount  |   date      |
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------------
|    1    |       1   |      5    |  2021-04-27 |
|    2    |       2   |      10   |  2021-04-26 |
|    3    |       3   |      15   |  2021-04-26 |
|    4    |       4   |      50   |  2021-04-25 |
```

So currently I can get the total account balance by location as of Today...

the problem is getting the account balance by location from data in history example 2021-04-01

the expected result is as illustrated below

```
Accounts as of 2021-04-01

| loc_id      |   balance |    date     |
|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|    1        |    200    |  2021-04-01 |
|    2        |    190    |  2021-04-01 |
|    3        |    -50    |  2021-04-01 |
|    4        |     10    |  2021-04-01 |
```

Comment: Please explain what "balance" has to do with the data you have provided.  There is no "balance" in any of the tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the total of account_bal  in users table

Comment: Then the `deposits` and `transactions` tables are not needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff wont you need to reverse transactions and deposits to get the users account balance in time?

Comment: . . I don't know.  You haven't explained the calculation.